# GridLayout look strange on a real Device and perfect on emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I've designed a basic calculator in android.
As i designed it, i tested it on Emulator Pixel XL Device (API 28, Screen Resolution 1440x2560 560dpi) and worked fine.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/iURX7cd.png] 
"Emulator Layout"

But when I installed the app in Huawei Honor 4C (Android 6.0) It look hilarious.
[image: https://i.imgur.com/ASBtE8y.png] 
"Huawei Honor 4c"

minimumSdkVersion: 21
targetSdkVersion: 28
My Design Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="end|bottom"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="5">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDivid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMultiplication"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:text="X" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:text="Delete" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="7"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="8"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="9"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="4"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="5"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="6"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="2"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="3"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEqual"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:text="=" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="0"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            android:tag="."
            android:text="." />


    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What are the possible reasons?

Comment: what is the targetSdkVersion

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 28.

Comment: do you get any solution? i am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that this apparent problem is related to the attribute android:supportsRtl="true" and the different API levels of your device/emualtor.
Add in manifest in application tag

```
<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
```

If set to true and targetSdkVersion is set to 17 or higher else false

Uninstall app in device and clear project then install to real device again.

If it works give me a thumbs up ..Keep coding :)

Comment: did you check in another mobile

Comment: No i did not check it in another mobile